# Lua Script problems on Super Nintendo emulation

Tags: lua, emulation

I'm currently trying to run a lua script to find the future values of a static rng seed from "Fire Emblem - Seisen no Keifu" in the snes9x-1.52-rr-r185 emulator by reading the memory values.

Unfortunately I get the following message when i run the code: "rng.lua:26: attempt to call field 'text' (a nil value)"

The code is below:

```
emu = snes9x
function get_rng()
    return {
        step  = memory.readbyte(0x7e04a2),
        table = memory.readbyterange(0x7e046b,0x37)
    }
end
function rand(rng)
    rng.step = rng.step + 1
    if rng.step >= 0x37 then
        for i = 0, 0x36 do
            local j if i < 0x18 then j = i+0x1f else j = i-0x18 end
            rng.table[i+1] = rng.table[i+1] - rng.table[j+1]
            if rng.table[i+1] < 0 then rng.table[i+1] = rng.table[i+1] + 100 end
        end
        rng.step = 0
    end
    local res = rng.table[rng.step+1]-1
    if res < 0 then res = 99 end
    return res
end

while true do
    local rng = get_rng()
    for i = 1, 0x10 do
        gui.text(i*12, 0,string.format("%02x",rng.step))
        gui.text(i*12,10,string.format("%2u",rand(rng)))
    end
    emu.frameadvance()
end
```

I expected the rng values to be shown on screen but got the aforementioned message.

Comment: What do you think `gui` is supposed to be there, and why do you think that?

Comment: My bad! I managed to get it to work. Seems I was too focused to find a simple mistake.
Thanks for the help anyways.